# Why is TypeScript allowing undefined methods?

Tags: jquery, typescript

I am trying to put together a presentation of TypeScript to the rest of my development team.  I'm trying to show them the type checking, however, I can't figure out why this example code is NOT failing at compile time on the ".notafunction" call.   ???

```html
/// <reference path="typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts" />

function greeting(person : any) {
    return "Hello " + person + "!";
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var user = ".Net Development Team";

    $("#greeting-header").notafunction(greeting(user));

});
```

Comment: It does lead to a compiler error for me. Maybe sharing your `tsconfig` will help?

And I also see you are including the jquery typings via `<reference/>`. Technically this should work, but you might want to switch to the recommended way of installing typings as NPM modules. You might want to consult this link https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/06/15/the-future-of-declaration-files/

Comment: I changed to import to import * as $ from "jquery";

Comment: @dade - Thanks for the response.

I changed to import to 
             import * as $ from "jquery";
I have tried using tsconfig.json and without.  I added this one:
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noEmitOnError": true
  }
}

I deleted my scripts/typings/jquery and tried using npm:

   npm install --save @types/jquery

MS Build did not find the defintitions in npm-modules\@types\jquery

I added that folder to my project and everything compiled again.  It did not catch the notafunction() call.

What was the error you received?

Comment: What is "`npm-modules`"?  I think you need to share more of your project configuration.  I also get the expected error: `Property 'notafunction' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'.`

Comment: @jcalz When I used "npm install --save @types/jquery" it created a folder in my project named "npm-modules" and put the jquery DefinitelyTyped files in a folder named "@types\jquery".

Comment: @jcalz It's interesting that your error indicates 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'.  My jquery.d.ts defines the result of '$()' as simply 'JQuery'.   My VS2017 says it's using Typescript 2 but I'm wondering if that's correct.

Answer (score 1):

OK I'm pretty sure the issue has something to do with the TypeScript and Typings inside VS2017.

The script/typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts that is installed with

```
Install-Package jquery.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped -Version 3.1.2
```

is different from the node_modules\@types\jquery\index.d.ts installed with

```
npm install --save @types/jquery
```

I was finally able to get typescript to install outside of VS2017 and I get the same error about JQuery.  When I switch back to the typings no more error.

Thank you for your information.